# Spring 2.2.1 Build error Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.5

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I am new with Spring boot framework and I added `spring-boot-starter-parent` 
am added spring-boot-starter-parent in my parent pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>     
</parent>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>Parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>7.0.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.compiler.version>1.8</java.compiler.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin>2.19.1</maven-surefire-plugin>
        <maven-assembly-plugin.version>2.5.5</maven-assembly-plugin.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.12</tomcat.version>
        <tomcat.8.0.version>8.0.50</tomcat.8.0.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.3</httpclient.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.5</jackson.version>
        <powermock.version>1.7.4</powermock.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.16</mockito.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <consul.version>0.14.0</consul.version>
        <json.version>20080701</json.version>
        <dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
        <implementation.version>7.0.0.0</implementation.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.compiler.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.compiler.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
    <modules>

    </modules>
</project>
```

Now it's showing an error in `pom.xml`.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.5 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I tried following solutions

- Update my maven project
- remove and rebuild the `.m2` folder

Please give suggestion on the above query.

Comment: Please post the whole pom.xml file

Comment: Seems to be there - have you tried `-U`?

Comment: i am updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jackson-bom version that maven is trying to resolve is not in the maven repository.When i checked the latest version is version [2.10.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom) . So, could you check if in your pom.xml anywhere you are explicitly setting the jackson version ? . If you try removing that and let maven resolve the version from spring.